# NSManagedObject NSNumber properties convert booleans to integers?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnumber

I am running into a problem with a NSManagedObject subclass where the value is set to boolean value, but the primitive type always seems to be an integer.

Here's a scenario that describes the problem:

If I have a method to check the primitive type of an NSNumber, like so:

```
- (BOOL) numberIsBool:(NSNumber*)numberToCheck {

   const char *primitiveType = [numberToCheck objCType];

   return (strcmp(primitiveType, @encode(BOOL)) == 0 );
 }
```

And I execute the following code:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

BOOL isBool = [self numberIsBool:num];
```

As expected, primitiveType will be "c" and isBool will be YES.

However, if I take the NSManagedObject subclass:

```
@interface MyClass : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myBoolValue;
...
@end
```

where myBoolValue is set to type Boolean in the model, and I execute the following code:

```
MyClass *myClass = ... (create from NSManagedObjectContext)

myClass.myBoolValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

BOOL isBool = [self numberIsBool:num];
```

primitiveType will be set to "i" and isBool will be NO

Can anyone explain to me the reason for this or how I can get the myBoolValue property to honor the primitive type it was set with?

EDIT: So there is no confusion on what I am trying to accomplish - I am NOT trying to convert the NSNumber to a boolean.  I already know how to do this with  `[myBoolValue boolValue]`.

EDIT #2 - More clarification: If I interrogate an NSManagedObject's properties.  When the property is an NSNumber and it's value is 1 or 0, I need to take a different code path if it was intended to be a boolean than if it was intended to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the post that @Nikita found, I realize that this was a shortcoming of NSManagedObject, so I figured out a solution to the problem:

```
- (BOOL) property:(NSString*)propertyName ofObjectIsBoolean:(NSObject*)object {
     BOOL isBoolean = NO;

     if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(entity)]) {

         NSEntityDescription *description = [object entity];

         NSDictionary *attributes = [description attributesByName];

         NSAttributeDescription *attributeDescription = [attributes objectForKey:propertyName];

         NSAttributeType attributeType = [attributeDescription attributeType];

         isBoolean = (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType);
      else {

         const char *primitiveType = [numberToCheck objCType];

         isBoolean = (strcmp(primitiveType, @encode(BOOL)) == 0 );
      }

      return isBoolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Core Data stores BOOLs as NSNFCNumbers.
To treat it like a BOOL you could tey this transform
`BOOL myBool = [[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@", (NSInteger)[myManagedObject valueForKey:@"myAttribute"]]intValue] == 1;`

Found the solution on Apple forums

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2169600?start=0&tstart=0

## EDIT

In your `numberIsBool` you should compare your primitiveType to **NSCFBoolean** ,because this is the type of BOOL that is stored in Core Data

Comment: I am not sure how this solves my problem.  I need to know, objectively, if the value was intended to be a bool or not.  Your solution requires me to know it was meant bool doesn't it? Or am I missing something?  In other words, if I interrogate an object to get it's properties, when I find an NSNumber with the value of 1 or 0, I need to take separate code branches if it was intended to be a boolean or an integer.  Make sense?

Comment: Soorry,didn't understood you right,i thought,you had some troubles with getting the BOOL value from NSManagedObject

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Don't you want just to add one more flag property?

Comment: While that could work, I already have a work around, what I want to know is why it behaves this way, because I don't think it should.  If I interrogate a regular NSObject class, I can tell the difference between booleans and integers, why can't I on NSManagedObjects?

Comment: Regarding your EDIT - primitiveType is "i" which is what is returned when the primitive type is an integer.

Comment: It feels like this is the question that suits really good to yours.Answer from Core Data god)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492726/core-data-mishandles-nscfboolean